# Getting hWnd of the VBA Project Properties Dialogbox Window

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with getting the hWnd of VBA project properties dialogbox.
I am trying to learn VBA and quite interested in VBE programming.
I read and successfully tested the instructions from the following link:

[Unprotect VBProject from VB code](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2019/01/20/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code/)

And after further reading at the following link:

http://www.standards.com/Office/SetVBAProjectPassword.html

and on trying to work out with information there, I found that I can't get a window handle hWnd of the VBA Project Properties dialogbox window without running another instance of Excel...

My questions are:

1.How do I get the hWnd of VBA Project Properties dialogbox window of the currently running instance of Excel?

2.Why can't I get the hWnd of VBA Project Properties dialogbox window without running a second instance of Excel?

I also attached the code that I copied and edited as follows.
This is my first Question here, so please forgive me for any formatting issues and if anybody find this post not following forum rules, please kindly let me know. I am more than ready to correct it.
I searched the forum posts already but only found minimally related topics which cannot entirely solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
 
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
 
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias _
"GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
 
Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

Dim Ret As Long, ChildRet As Long, OpenRet As Long
Dim strBuff As String, ButCap As String
 
Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Const BM_CLICK = &HF5

'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
        GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
        Major:=5, Minor:=3

Sub test1()
Dim hWndOfProjectPropertiesOfThisProject As Long
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True, Visible:=False).Execute
    'hWndOfProjectPropertiesOfThisProject = GetActiveWindow
    'Debug.Print hWndOfProjectPropertiesOfThisProject
    GethWndOfProjectPropertiesWindow
End Sub

Sub test2()
    OpenANewExcel
    GethWndOfProjectPropertiesWindow
End Sub

Sub OpenANewExcel()
Dim xlAp As Object, oWb As Object, sWb As Object
Dim strpath As String
    
    Set xlAp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlAp.Visible = True

    strpath = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" + ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set oWb = xlAp.Workbooks.Open(strpath)
    oWb.Activate
    xlAp.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
    xlAp.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True, Visible:=False).Execute
End Sub

Sub GethWndOfProjectPropertiesWindow()
    Dim hWndProjectProperties As Long
    hWndProjectProperties = FindWindow(vbNullString, "VBAProject - Project Properties")
    Debug.Print "hWnd = " & hWndProjectProperties
End Sub
```

I've also read the cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx (can't post more than 2 links)

Comment: 1. Use a timer; and 2. because  your code will stop when you show that dialog. 3. Why can't you use a separate instance?

Comment: I can use a separate instance. The problem with separate instance is that after I close the original instance, the second instance will wait a few moments to show a read/write dialog which in my opinion is not very elegant.
I'm not sure but I don't think the code execution stopped when I show that dialog (I already checked by adding debug.prints before and after showing that dialog. But may be I'm wrong.
If code execution stop when that dialog is shown, why didn't it stop when a second instance is run?
I'm not trying to be smart because I'm not smart and I'm just learning.

Comment: It's OK, I might be misremembering and the dialog may not be modal. But you need a pause to allow the window to be shown before FindWindow runs.

Comment: Timer means using Application.OnTime function? to call the FindWindow API function?
Sorry, I'm still learning VBA.
That dialog box is Modal yes. But when I checked with debug.print, it printed out before and after the API call.

Comment: No, a windows timer using the SetTimer API. See example below.

Comment: I added DoEvents before the call to GethWnd still not showing hWnd. Will it suffice for need of a pause?

Comment: Not reliably, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using a timer. I can make no guarantees that this will work reliably. I have used it in the past purely as a theoretical test and it worked, but was never 100% reliable across all Excel versions or OS options, that I recall. (as I've never had a use for such code, I've never pursued it further)

```
Option Explicit
Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
                              ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal hwndChildAfter As Long, _
                              ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long
Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uCmd As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDlgItem Lib "user32" ( _
                            ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
                             ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
                             ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Declare Function SetFocusAPI Lib "user32" Alias "SetFocus" ( _
                             ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "user32" (ByVal hwndLock As Long) As Long
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Const WM_CLOSE = &H10
Public Const WM_GETTEXT = &HD
Public Const EM_REPLACESEL = &HC2
Public Const EM_SETSEL = &HB1
Public Const BM_CLICK = &HF5&
Public Const TCM_SETCURFOCUS = &H1330&
  Const IDTab = &H3020&
  Const IDLockProject = &H1557&
  Const IDPassword = &H155E&
  Const IDConfirmPassword = &H1556&
  Const IDOK = &H1&

Private Const TimeoutSecond = 2

Private g_ProjectName    As String
Private g_Password       As String
Private g_hwndVBE        As Long
Private g_Result         As Long
Private g_hwndPassword   As Long


Public Function UnlockTimerProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
                                ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal dwTime As Long) As Long
   Dim hwndProjectProp As Long, hwndProjectProp2 As Long
   Dim hwndTab As Long, hwndLockProject As Long, hwndPassword As Long
   Dim hwndConfirmPassword As Long, hwndOK As Long
   Dim hWndTmp As Long, lRet As Long
   Dim IDTab As Long, IDLockProject As Long, IDPassword As Long
   Dim IDConfirmPassword As Long, IDOK As Long
   Dim sCaption          As String
   Dim timeout As Date, timeout2 As Date
   Dim pwd               As String

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   KillTimer 0, idEvent
   sCaption = " Password"

   'for the japanese version
   Select Case Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
      Case 1041
         sCaption = ChrW(&H30D7) & ChrW(&H30ED) & ChrW(&H30B8) & _
                    ChrW(&H30A7) & ChrW(&H30AF) & ChrW(&H30C8) & _
                    ChrW(&H20) & ChrW(&H30D7) & ChrW(&H30ED) & _
                    ChrW(&H30D1) & ChrW(&H30C6) & ChrW(&H30A3)
   End Select

   sCaption = g_ProjectName & sCaption
   timeout = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, TimeoutSecond)
   Do While Now() < timeout

      hwndPassword = 0
      hwndOK = 0

      hWndTmp = 0
      Do
         hWndTmp = FindWindowEx(0, hWndTmp, vbNullString, sCaption)
         If hWndTmp = 0 Then Exit Do
      Loop Until GetParent(hWndTmp) = g_hwndVBE
      If hWndTmp = 0 Then GoTo Continue
      Debug.Print "found window"
      lRet = SendMessage(hWndTmp, TCM_SETCURFOCUS, 1, ByVal 0&)

      hwndPassword = GetDlgItem(hWndTmp, IDPassword)
      Debug.Print "hwndpassword: " & hwndPassword

      hwndOK = GetDlgItem(hWndTmp, IDOK)
      Debug.Print "hwndOK: " & hwndOK

      If (hWndTmp _
          And hwndOK) = 0 Then GoTo Continue

      lRet = SetFocusAPI(hwndPassword)
      lRet = SendMessage(hwndPassword, EM_SETSEL, 0, ByVal -1&)
      lRet = SendMessage(hwndPassword, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, ByVal g_Password)

      pwd = String(260, Chr(0))
      lRet = SendMessage(hwndPassword, WM_GETTEXT, Len(pwd), ByVal pwd)
      pwd = Left(pwd, InStr(1, pwd, Chr(0), 0) - 1)
      If pwd <> g_Password Then GoTo Continue
    lRet = SetTimer(0, 0, 100, AddressOf ClosePropertiesWindow)

      lRet = SetFocusAPI(hwndOK)
      lRet = SendMessage(hwndOK, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&)

      g_Result = 1
      Exit Do

Continue:
      DoEvents
      Sleep 100
   Loop
       Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
   If hwndPassword <> 0 Then SendMessage hwndPassword, WM_CLOSE, 0, ByVal 0&
   LockWindowUpdate 0
End Function



Function UnlockProject(ByVal Project As Object, ByVal Password As String) As Long
    Dim timeout               As Date
    Dim lRet                  As Long

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    UnlockProject = 1
    If Project.Protection <> vbext_pp_locked Then
        UnlockProject = 2
        Exit Function
    End If

    g_ProjectName = Project.Name
    g_Password = Password
    '    LockWindowUpdate GetDesktopWindow()
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.visible = True
    g_hwndVBE = Application.VBE.MainWindow.hWnd
    g_Result = 0
    lRet = SetTimer(0, 0, 100, AddressOf UnlockTimerProc)
    If lRet = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "error setting timer"
        GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If
    Set Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject = Project
    If Not Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject Is Project Then
        GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If
    Application.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=2578).Execute

    timeout = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, TimeoutSecond)
    Do While g_Result = 0 And Now() < timeout
        DoEvents
    Loop
    If g_Result Then
        UnlockProject = 0
    End If

    AppActivate Application.Caption
    LockWindowUpdate 0
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    AppActivate Application.Caption
    LockWindowUpdate 0
End Function

Sub Test_UnlockProject()
   Select Case UnlockProject(ActiveWorkbook.VBProject, "test")
      Case 0: MsgBox "The project was unlocked."
      Case 2: MsgBox "The active project was already unlocked."
      Case Else: MsgBox "Error or timeout."
   End Select
End Sub

Function ClosePropertiesWindow(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
                                ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal dwTime As Long) As Long
   Dim timeout As Date
   Dim hWndTmp As Long
   Dim hwndOK As Long
   Dim lRet As Long
   Dim sCaption As String


   sCaption = g_ProjectName & " - Project Properties"
    Debug.Print sCaption

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
   KillTimer 0, idEvent

   timeout = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, TimeoutSecond)
   Do While Now() < timeout

      hWndTmp = 0
      Do
         hWndTmp = FindWindowEx(0, hWndTmp, vbNullString, sCaption)
         If hWndTmp = 0 Then Exit Do
      Loop Until GetParent(hWndTmp) = g_hwndVBE
      If hWndTmp = 0 Then GoTo Continue
      Debug.Print "found properties window"
      lRet = SendMessage(hWndTmp, TCM_SETCURFOCUS, 1, ByVal 0&)

      hwndOK = GetDlgItem(hWndTmp, IDOK)
      Debug.Print "hwndOK: " & hwndOK
      If (hWndTmp _
          And hwndOK) = 0 Then GoTo Continue

      lRet = SetFocusAPI(hwndOK)
      lRet = SendMessage(hwndOK, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&)

      g_Result = 1
      Exit Do

Continue:
      DoEvents
      Sleep 100
   Loop
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number
   LockWindowUpdate 0
End Function
```

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply, Sir.
Let me work on it and reply tomorrow and to confirm it as an answer.

Comment: many thanks again for sharing your code.
I got it working after several hours working on it.
Like you said, initially, I can't get it working on my 64bit-Win8.1, 32bit-Excel2010.
But after including some missing API functions and replacing the GetDlgItem API calls with FindWindowEx, I got it beautifully working!

I still don't get why the running VBA code cannot directly get the hWnd of Project Properties Dialog while another instance and timer can.
It's an Office?/Windows? restriction? like AutoIT cannot be used to find it's own hWnd?
Anyway, it's a sign for me to study further.

Comment: I just figured that the code execution must have been stopped as the Project Properties Dialogbox is modal...